# Convex, closed, bounded subset of a reflexive space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a reflexive Banach space and let $K \subset E$ be convex, closed and bounded. Show $K$ is compact in the weak topology on $E$.

Comment: I translated to the best of my ability. Please let me know if anything is incorrect.

Comment: These sort of problems just scream Banach Alaoglu.

Answer (score 4):

Since $K$ is convex and norm-closed, it is closed in the weak-topology, and since $K$ is norm-bounded, it is contained in some norm-closed ball, which is weakly compact by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem (we can apply it to the weak topology since $E$ is reflexive).  Thus $K$ is a weakly closed subset of a weakly compact set, hence $K$ is weakly compact.